# KenBurnsView creating smooth custom animation

Tags: android, splash-screen, dynamic-splash-screen, android-kenburnsview

I'm using the KenBurnsView library in [here](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView)

But transition is not smooth and I don't know how to use the following code noted on github:

```
RandomTransitionGenerator generator = new RandomTransitionGenerator(duration, interpolator);
kbv.setTransitionGenerator(generator);
```

Can anyone help me how to create a smooth transition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you already have a `KenBurnsView` type object i.e `kvb`. To add a custom transition as the docs says and you also suggest.

**Make**

```
RandomTransitionGenerator generator = new RandomTransitionGenerator(duration, interpolator);
```

`RandomTransitionGenerator` is a [class already included in the lib](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/flaviofaria/kenburnsview/RandomTransitionGenerator.java).

> It takes 2 parameters :

1) `duration` i.e in miliseconds (usualy that the case)

2) [`interpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) - it is more like the effect of animation or rate of change of an animation.

We need to make an object of type `Interpolator` and use it like :

```
AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator ACCELERATE_DECELERATE = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
RandomTransitionGenerator generator = new RandomTransitionGenerator(10000, ACCELERATE_DECELERATE);
//duration = 10000ms = 10s and interpolator = ACCELERATE_DECELERATE
kbv.setTransitionGenerator(generator); //set new transition on kbv
```

the docs also adds that if you need more customization you can make your own `TransitionGenerator` class like `RandomTransitionGenerator`

Comment: Was  the animation then smoother ?

Comment: Hi, @Kushal Sharma, it works on simulator well, but it does not work on phone smoothly. Any suggestion?